# Correct usage of OR logical operator

Tags: java, while-loop

So im having this loop. as you can se the loop is supposed to run if the d1 (users input) is not "g" or "u". the purpose is to force the user to answer a question. but i can't make it work.

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
d1 = user_input.next();
while (!"g".equals(d1) || !"u".equals(d1)) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("");
    d1 = user_input.next();
}
```

i know from the past that this will work:

```
while (!"g".equals(d1)) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("");
    d1 = user_input.next();
}
```

I think it has something to do with this "or logical operator" ||

Comment: You're only reading the user input once.

Comment: Also, please put your post in Question form. :)

Comment: Yes it has. I do not code in Java but you should use the `and` logical operator instead of the `or` logical operator

Comment: @JuanRocamonde There are flags in SO as `this is a comment not an answer`. Yours' is the other way round!. I would like to flag your comment as `This is an answer and not a comment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition should be:

```
while (!"g".equals(d1) && !"u".equals(d1)) {
```

instead of

```
while (!"g".equals(d1) || !"u".equals(d1)) {
```

Comment: Upvote for answering the question while I was still typing :)

Comment: What i've just commented. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `d1` can't simultaneously equal `"g"` *and* `"u"` then the loop condition will *always* be true.  You probably meant to negate the entire condition, not the individual conditions:

```
while (!("g".equals(d1) || "u".equals(d1)))
```

or, similarly (and maybe easier to read):

```
while (!"g".equals(d1) && !"u".equals(d1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saying "if user input is not g" OR "if user input is not u"... wouldn't AND be a better operator for what you're trying to do? As in "if user input is neither g nor u":

Use && rather than || if so.